# cakephp paginate second page does not display icons

Tags: cakephp, pagination

My main page displays a list of post,  with an icon  at the beginning of each popst.

When I click next page (paginator),  all lines are displayed  without icons.   There is an square insstead of the icons.

Thank you for your help

I'm linking the icon in the following way

```
<img src="webroot\img\cake.icon.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: how are you linking to the icon (provide code)? The link got broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webroot\img\cake.icon.png` appears to be a server path, not a URL path, which is what's needed.

Try changing the image's src attribute to `/img/cake.icon.png` or, if your CakePHP installation is in a subdirectory, to `/subdir/img/cake.icon.png`

Comment: Hello, maybe I was not clear in my explanation.  It works when I'm in the first page,  when I click to go to the second page, icons dont appear.  I've tried with /webroot/img/cake.icon.png  but I still have the same problem

Comment: Don't use `webroot`, use the directory belonging to your CakePHP install. If you've installed CakePHP at `http://www.whatever.com/cake/`, then your image src should be `/cake/img/cake.icon.png`.